# Broadcom 55xx drivers causing issues on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers

Linux beginner here.

Trying to install wireless on fresh Ubuntu, but the drivers are proprietary so some fiddling is required. Tried to install the rpm driver package from Broadcasts homepage, but I couldn't find the rpm path on Ubuntu and both terminal and Google insisted that I should use Alien instead. So I used alien to install the driver, but I think I need to build the driver aswell and not just install it. Couldn't figure out how to do that with Alien.

Grateful for any help!

Comment: Which device do you have ? Is it a USB or PCI/PCI-E device ?

Comment: It's an integrated Broadcom 5xx netextreme on a Dell Latitude laptop. dpkg -l | grep 'tg3' tells me that the driver is installed (I think?) but I don't have wireless access, so I guess I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: can you post the output of lspci -k somewhere ? also lsmod as well ?

Comment: 0c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5761 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
 Subsystem: Dell Device 053d
 Kernel driver in use: tg3
 Kernel modules: tg3

Comment: That's for the wired ethernet. Is there one in there for the Wireless ?

Comment: lsmod text: http://txt.do/10r1

Comment: lspci text http://txt.do/10rr

Comment: Ok, it looks like the module is loaded. What's the output of ifconfig -a ?

Comment: http://txt.do/10ro